# Avoiding "Stack offset of X exceeded max offset" error

Tags: rust, program

I'm trying to understand how to best avoid this Stack error.  At first I thought this was just related to serialising/deserialising data as if i tried to get more than 4096 in one chunk I got the error, but now I am getting it even when trying to deserialise and store an array of 256 U64 values, so 2048 bytes, but it works if i just try and get 128 values.

Are there any 'tricks' to avoiding this error?  I.e. is the stack just local in scope so that if i get the data in a function and use it there then it is fine?

Is there any easy way to work out what is using up all the space?  Is every 'let' definition going on the stack?

Many Thanks for any help understanding this!

Edit with more info: I'm not using Anchor, the source code (that compiles with an error) is available here:

https://github.com/daoplays/solana_examples/tree/master/charity_lottery/program/src

the function in question is the select_winners function in processor.rs

Edit 2:

I've tried to pull the offending functionality into its own function :

```
fn select_one_winner(idx : usize, cumulative_total : &mut u64, threshold : u64, found_winner : &mut bool, winner_index : &mut usize, program_data_account_info : &AccountInfo) -> ProgramResult
{

    let bid_idx = get_state_index(StateEnum::BidAmounts {index: idx*256});

    let bids = BidValues::try_from_slice(&program_data_account_info.data.borrow()[bid_idx.0..bid_idx.0+256*8])?; 

    for bid_index in 0..256 {

        let current_bid = bids.bid_amounts[bid_index];
        
        *cumulative_total += current_bid;

        if *cumulative_total > threshold {

            *found_winner = true;
            *winner_index = idx * 256 + bid_index;

            break;


        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

but this still gives the following error;
Error: Function _ZN19charity_lottery_v029processor9Processor17select_one_winner17hff9ee0a19780eb8bE Stack offset of 6200 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 2104 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

Given all I am doing here is getting 256 U64s and then iterating over them, i'm really not sure why this yields a stack size of 6200.

Comment: It could be useful if you give out more details. Are you using Anchor or are you solely using Solana? Where are you encountering this error?

Comment: @hrs8 have updated with a link to the code repo and the function in question that is failing to compile

Answer (score 1):

Try `Box`ing `bids` to move it from stack to heap. `let bids = Box::new(BidValues::try_...`